# how to make an app that automate rideshare/restaurants app requests (ex. mystro)

Tags: android, mobile

does anyone have any idea how to make an app that automates and filter rideshare/restaurant apps requests? It's kinda working as an umbrella for more than one app.
for example, the XYZ app will be in the foreground and will monitor both Uber Eats and Postmate in the background and whenever requests are received it will show on the XYZ app screen with its details.
I believe it's not doable on the IOS but its existing on android on an app called Mystor. it uses somehow advisability functions in the phone but I want to understand the logic behind it and know how does it work?